# Client-Server implementation for uploading a file using Socket

Tags: client-server

I want to implement a Client-Server program in which the client has to send a file to the server. In this case, what is the efficient way to send the file to server?

I am thinking in the following method,

After the connection establishment, First, I have to send the file name (which i want to upload) to server from client. Then I have to send the file content to server. The server will wait for the file content after received the file name from client.

So, for uploading a file, I need 2 write method in client & 2 read method in server.

Is this ok? Is there any other efficient way for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your idea is correct. Maybe you should consider not to send files name (only the extension line .jpg) and let server generate one. This will prevent overwriting some already existing files.